# R1 Joystick Controller as Bluetooth mouse

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, game-controllers

I have an [R1 Bluetooth controller](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005003771974663.html). When I connect this controller to my Android tablet, it is well recognized in Bluetooth but at the functional level, it works like a joystick. That is to say, when I move the joystick, it selects the tabs.

What I would like is that this joystick works like a mouse and they indicate a mouse cursor. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

It is a joystick.  Joysticks generally just have a make/break switch, so I think it will not be very successful, even if you could achieve it.  I can't see it being very precise either.

It is possible, but you will need an app that someone has written just for it. I can find many solutions for [Windows](https://assistive.co.nz/product/joystick-to-mouse/) and [Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Gamepad), but none for Android.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is